# How do I determine which variables to pick in a binomial GLMM using lme4?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I'm still pretty new to modelling but essentially, the dataset is consists of the following (the first observation only):

```
              SeedAttachment.Number  Seed NO.seed Species   Syndrome     Mountain    Individual Method   
              <dbl>                  <dbl> <dbl>  <chr>    <fct>        <chr>       <chr>      <fct>        
 1              5                     1       4  SpeciesC Intermediate Bluff Knoll 11690-000  Separate
```

So the data was collected and contains almost 1000+ observations. I want to determine **whether different syndromes have different levels of production of seeds**. The SeedAttachment.Number represents an appendage in the plant connecting to the "Seed" and sometimes, the Seed number is less than the SeedAttachment.Number. Syndrome is the pollination syndrome and is the suite of plant traits - it is either bee, bird or both. Mountain is the location of plant sample. Individual is the plant ID. Method can be ignored.

What is the best way to build out the formula for a Generalised Linear Mixed Effect model using a binomial distribution?

I have identified fixed effects as Syndrome. The random effect would probably be Mountain, Species and Individual.

```
model <- glmer(cbind(Seed, NO.seed) ~ Syndrome + (1|Species/Individual) + (1|Mountain),family = binomial, data=d1)
```

```
model2 <-  glmer(cbind(Seed, NO.seed) ~ Syndrome + (1|Species / Individual), family = binomial, data = d1)
```

As I understand it; `(1|Species / Individual)` means that it's a  nested random effect. ie. Individual is nested within Species cluster.

When I try fitting both models, can someone explain why I'm getting the following error?

```
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

Also, how do I determine what is the best variables to fit? I don't understand the effect off leaving some variables off or on. Like, which one do I select to answer the research question above?

How do I plot the data so I can visualise the slopes within each random effect cluster and the fixed slope for the overall data?

Comment: A typical reason for singular fit in multilevel models is that while the data is clustered, cluster-specific variance is close to zero. Could you post your outputs for these models? Also, how many observations do you have per each individual plant?